# Squaring Both Sides of Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

I am trying to understand why this is allowed:

$$\mathsf P(|X - u| \ge t) = \mathsf P(|X-u|^2 \ge t^2)$$

I understand you can square both sides of an equality, i.e. $a = b \Rightarrow  a^2 = b^2$

I don't understand why this must be true within a probability inequality.

Comment: No, it's not allowed unless $t \ge 0$.

Comment: The only thing that matters here is whether the condition |X-u| ≥ t is logically equivalent to the condition |X-u|^2 ≥ t^2. **If** that is true, then the two probabilities are the probability of the very same event, hence equal. (**However**, if t < 0, then the two conditions are *not* equivalent.)

Comment: $(|c|)^2=c^2$ and $a \ge b \ge 0 \implies a^2 \ge b^2 \ge 0$.  So your expression is correct provided that $t \ge 0$.  Otherwise a counterexample to your statement might have $X$ taking values between $-1$ and $1$ and $u=0$ with $t=-3$ in which case you would have $P(|X - 0| \ge -3) = 1 \not = 0 = P(|X-0|^2 \ge 9)$

Comment: Thanks, the ≥0 detail had escaped me while I was reading the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two events whose probability you are computing are the same event (of course assuming $t\geq 0.$)

$$E_1=\{\omega: |X(w) - u| \geq t\} = \{\omega :|X(\omega)-u|^2 \geq t^2\}=E_2$$

where $\omega \in \Omega,$ and $\Omega$ is the sample space.